# persist debian package on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, deb

I have an Ubuntu server that I recompiled libcurl for sftp support. The problem is when the server is rebooted or updated I have to reinstall the curl package. I am not clear how to persist this package, like set an ignore with apt? or something?

To install:

```
sudo dpkg-i libcurl3_7.19.7-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

I am running Ubuntu 10.04

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"

2.6.32-33-server #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:21:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should understand, that if a package is getting replaced during an upgrade, that is being done for a valid reason.  Whenever that happens, you should look very closely at the changelog for that package, there is a good chance that it is being updated related to some security vulnerability.  If that is the case, then you should almost certainly be downloading the updated source, and re-building your local package.

In any case if you want to force a package to not be updated, you need set it to the **hold** state.  To set a package to be held run the command `aptitude hold {packagename}`, or in your case `aptitude hold libcurl3`.

Comment: Thanks! That sorted the issue. I would vote you up but I don't have 15+ rep points.

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted, but you might need to wait a bit longer.